# Seeking help setting up a micro instance on AWS EC2 for a simple "hello world" app

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny-server

I'm trying to get a working app on a micro instance on amazon ec2.

I've been using the ami (ami-e2a3358b) I found from a blog post at http://trestletechnology.net/2013/02/deploying-shiny-server-on-amazon-ec2/

I've been learning about using EC2 but it is new to me.  I'm using putty and winSCV to connect to the machine.

Now I think I'm at the stage where I want to make a config file and put my app in a ShinyApps folder.  I've read over config.html in /shiny-server but I am having some trouble putting all the pieces together.  I've also looked at http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/ but I haven't figured it all out.

I just want to have a single ShinyApps folder I can put my apps in with a shiny-server.conf file that will recognize where that folder is.

What config file do I need to put in /shiny-server directory?  Where do want to put my ShinyApps folder for this config file?  And what is the final address (and port?) that I want to put in the url bar to get to the app?

Thanks for any responses. If I haven't been clear its from ignorance so help me out and ask me a question if I need to elaborate.

Comment: I would check the version of shiny server running on that AMI ami-e2a3358b it may not be uptodate so any advice on conf files may not work for the version running.

Comment: its says 0.3.0 in package.json

Comment: I would avoid spending too much time on this. That version is deprecated. Follow the rest of that blog post and create your own AMI installing a current shiny-server v 1.0 which got bumped from version 0.5.0

Comment: Actually that post is not the best now as shiny-server is no longer installed that way.

Comment: What's a good install tutorial for the most recent version?

Comment: I would start up a ubuntu 12.04 instance and install as per http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/install-opensource .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a conf file at /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

```
john@ubuntu:~$ more /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
# Define the user we should use when spawning R Shiny processes
run_as shiny;

# Define a top-level server which will listen on a port
server {
  # Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
  #listen 3838 127.0.0.1;
  listen 3838;

  location /userApps {
    user_apps;
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

Then for example user john would just need to have a Shinyapps directory in their home directory. This was the case for [2014-03-18 17:43:01.113] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v0.4.0.15 (Node.js v0.10.21) maybe different now.

Comment: and would the dns be DNS:3838/myapp ?

Comment: For `user_apps`, the URL would be prefaced by the username. So if you had an app in `/home/john/ShinyApps/app1`, the URL would be `<DNS>:3838/john/app1`